# Pie chart filemaker with 3 different cattegories

Tags: graph, pie-chart, filemaker

I have a small testing database with the following data:
**Table: Workers**, with fields

```
Id  
FirstName  
LastName  
Sex (I only include 3 options: man, woman, other)  
Number_men  
Number_women  
Number_others
```

What I want to do right now is to display a pie chart showing the number of men, women and others as percentage, but so far my efforts have proven worthless, as the best I've accomplished is a graph showing 3 times the same value and the same label.

Answer (score 0):

You need a summary field to calculate the sum for each group in the found set.

```
Id
FirstName   
LastName    
Sex 
Sex_count   Summary = Count of Sex
```

Set up the slice data setting to use the summary field and sort the found set on Sex.

[image: Example pie chart]